Optimization Docker Image
I have a dockerfile for a Cloud Run app, it has certain idiosincracies that add size to the image,like the fact that i have to "RUN pip uninstall -y opencv-python && pip install --no-cache-dir opencv-python-headless" for the ultralytics package to work. How would you guys suggest optimizing it? My imports are:
import os
from ultralytics import YOLO
import io
import vertexai
from vertexai.preview.generative_models import GenerativeModel
from vertexai.preview.generative_models import Image as ImageVertex
from PIL import Image
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud import bigquery
from datetime import datetime, timezone
from google.cloud import storage
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash, session, jsonify, send_from_directory
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

The Dockerfile looks like this:
FROM python:3.12.3-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        ffmpeg \
        libsm6 \
        libxext6 && \
    apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir \
        numpy \
        pillow && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir \
        ipython\
        opencv-python \
        google-cloud-vision  \
        google-cloud-aiplatform  \
        gunicorn \
        google-cloud-storage\
        vertexai\
        flask && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir \
        torch torchvision --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir \
        ultralytics

RUN pip uninstall -y opencv-python && pip install --no-cache-dir opencv-python-headless

# Set the environment variable for the port**
ENV PORT 8080

# Set the working directory**
WORKDIR /home

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /home**
COPY . /home

# Expose the application port**
EXPOSE 8080

# Command to run the application**
CMD ["python3", "main.py"]

Its a 2.4 GB image, i dont know how to proceed.I tried separating Build and runtime stages and it barely made any difference.

Is there an actual issue? If there's 2 gigabytes of libraries you need, then there's 2 gigabytes of libraries.

Basically just wanted to see wether somebody knows a way of optimizing imports and uninstalls to lighten the image. But trying it out maybe this is as light as it gets. I am not using many dependencies of ultralytics for example but the way the package is designed doesnt allow me to uninstall them. Matplotlib is not needed in my code but i cant unistall it, same with seaborn.

Well, yeah, Ultralytics is poorly designed in that sense. (By the way, it will call home every time you use it unless you tell it not to.)

Interesting thread, i will take it in note. I dont think that atm i have enough time to rewrite the library but tbh there are many glaring issues with how they have managed the whole package(open-cv-headless). Quite annoying cause it limits the possibilities of developing fast light tools with YOLO, unless you want to put in the time to make it custom. All the optimizations that i can do lightens the image 10 mb lol, Thanks tho

You can of course fork the repo, add a commit (on a branch called fix-requirements in this example) that fixes the dependencies in pyproject.toml to something suiting you better and point pip to then install git+https://github.com/pgb314/ultralytics@fix-requirements

Thats a great and quite simple idea, thanks for the Help, much obliged :)
